# Что не так с кодировкой и что можно предпринять?

Tags: c#, csv, epplus

Написал код, который парсит xlsx файл и выплевывает в csv. 
При экспорте, данные на английском языке отображаются корректно. А вот кириллица нет. (кракозябры), как я понял это траблы с кодировкой.

Это файл экспорта [Экспорт](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2ke2cr598z1xy2/Export.csv?dl=0)
Это файл импорта  [Импорт](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dppcmy9gdr3026q/import.xlsx?dl=0)

Он-лайн декодер подсказывает, что эскпортированный текст имеет кодировку WIN1251
[Декодер](http://www.online-decoder.com/ru)

Для примера можете взять один из столбцов: "Ð‘Ð¾Ð»Ñ‚"

Он также определяет что на самом деле для правильного отображения (интерпретации?) нужна кодировака UTF-8.

Проблема в том что я не могу понять, какая часть моего кода работает не правильно, импортирующая, или экспортирующая, ведь при дебаггинге никаких кракозябр в листах с ячейками нет. Все отображается корректно.

Вот мой импортирующий код (для импорта используется библиотека EPPlus:

```
 try { 
        FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(path);
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
        {

            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];   // данные всегда на первом листе. 

            int row = GetDimensionRows(worksheet); // узнаем сколько строк в таблице.


            for (int r = 1; r <= row; r++) // считываем все строки
            {
                string[] buff = new string[18]; // создаем буфер строки эксель из 18 ячеек. (18 колонок)
                for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) // сканируем 18 колонок (с 1 по 18)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Value = null; //убираем мусор

                        Value = worksheet.Cells[r, i].Value.ToString(); // получаем значение ячейки

                       // Value = GetRightEncoding(Value); // конвертируем в правильную кодировку.
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException)
                    {
                        Value = "empty";
                        System.Console.WriteLine("JDC: обработано пустое значение ячейки");
                    }
                    buff[i-1] = Value.ToString(); // Засовываем отсканированные стролбцы в буфер
                }
```

Вот мой экспортирующий код (использована библиотека jitbit/CsvExport):

```
try
            {
                export.AddRow();
                export["handleId"] = input[i].massive[0];
                export["fieldType"] = input[i].massive[1];
                export["name"] = input[i].massive[2];
                export["description"] = input[i].massive[3];
                export["productImageUrl"] = input[i].massive[4];
                export["collection"] = input[i].massive[5];
                export["sku"] = input[i].massive[6];
                export["ribbon"] = input[i].massive[7];
                export["price"] = input[i].massive[8];
                export["surcharge"] = input[i].massive[9];
                export["visible"] = input[i].massive[10];
                export["discountValue"] = input[i].massive[11];
                export["inventory"] = input[i].massive[12];
                export["weight"] = input[i].massive[13];
                export["productOptionName1"] = input[i].massive[14];
                export["productOptionDescription1"] = input[i].massive[15];
            }
            catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("JDC: При попытке записи, метод обратился к несуществующему звену массива");
            }
export.ExportToFile(MakePath(Program.GlobalPath) + "Export.csv", 8);
```

Если вас заинтерисует то вот код метода экспорта из библиотеки, немного доработанный:

```
public void ExportToFile(string path, int encodingType)
    {

        if (encodingType == 8)
            try { File.WriteAllLines(path, ExportToLines(), Encoding.UTF8); }
            catch (System.IO.IOException)
            {
                //No access to file
            }
        if (encodingType == 32)
            try { File.WriteAllLines(path, ExportToLines(), Encoding.UTF32); }
            catch (System.IO.IOException)
            {
                //No access to file
            }

    }
```

Помогите разобраться, где зарыта собака, в идеале если проблема в интерпретации еще на этапе импорта данных то можно огранизовать метод перекодирования после строки:  `Value = worksheet.Cells[r, i].Value.ToString();`
Что собственно вы и можете видеть (закоментированный метод - это мои вчерашние попытки)

Код метода:

```
  public static  string GetRightEncoding(string input)
    {
        string output = null;
   //     Encoding utf8 = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
   //     Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");


        //byte[] utf8Bytes = win1251.GetBytes(input);
        //byte[] win1251Bytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, win1251, utf8Bytes);
        //output = win1251.GetString(win1251Bytes);



        // byte[] win1251Bytes = win1251.GetBytes(input);
        //byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(win1251, utf8, win1251Bytes);


        //  var fromEncodind = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");//из какой кодировки
        //  var bytes = fromEncodind.GetBytes(input);
        //  var toEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");//в какую кодировку
        //  output = toEncoding.GetString(bytes);
        //string s = new string(Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251").GetChars(input.toByte));
        return output;
    } //Конвертирует строку в нужную кодировку
```

Как бы я не изворачивался - при включении метода (там тестировалось несколько кусков кода) - все становится только хуже. Кажется я зашел в тупик.

Comment: Открыл ваш файл экспорта через FAR в кодировке UTF-8, все клапаны, болты и прочие гидрокомпенсаторы видны по-русски. Судя по коду, вы этого и добивались?

Comment: Непонимаю как у вас это получилось... вот открываю в Excel - кракозябры, дефолтная кодировка в Excel вроде как и есть UTF-8. Но почему то когда я открываю файл export.csv  в ексель, оторбажаются кракозябры.

Я решил что проблема в моем коде а не в екселе, потому что взял ячейку с кракозябрами, отправил в он лайн конвертер, а он показал что для того чтобы то что я ему дал, не было кракозябрами, надо интерпретировать текст как win1251.. Соотвественно меня это смутило и я полез на форум в поисках решения.

Comment: это один из известнейших моментов, что csv нужно не кликать чтобы открылось, а делать импорт и указывать формат. https://habr.com/en/company/mailru/blog/129476/

Comment: Понятно что если открыть через импорт текста в екселе то подобрав кодировку можно получить читаемое. Мне надо чтобы отображение было нормальным подефолту.